# Using DateTime.Quarter in LinQ Group

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I need to group by quarter in a LinQ expression. here is the code with year:

```
temp = rmds.GroupBy(a => new { a.reportinggroup, a.timestep.Year })
           .Select(g => ....}).ToList();
```

Now I would like to replace `DateTime.Year` in the GroupBy with a quarter expression. Here is my extension mehtod:

```
public static int quarter(this DateTime @this)
{
    return (int) Math.Ceiling((double)@this.Month / 3);
}
```

But if I replace this in my LinQ:

```
 temp = rmds.GroupBy(a => new { a.reportinggroup, a.timestep.quarter() });
```

I get following error:

> Error 1 Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.

Why? What do I need to use to group by quarter please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is telling you what the options are. The `a.timestep.quarter()` part is invalid as written because:

- It's not a member assignment (e.g. `foo = a.timestep.quarter()`)
- It's not a simple name (e.g. just `timestep`)
- It's not a member access (which e.g. `a.reportinggroup` is)

So this is what you need to do:

```
temp = rmds.GroupBy(a => new { a.reportinggroup, quarter = a.timestep.quarter() })
```

Comment: what is the difference here??

Comment: `The error message is telling you what the options are.` That answers a lot of SO questions these days :)

Comment: @Neel: The difference is the `quarter = `.